# Solving a specific design question using generics: correct in this case?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, domain-driven-design

Let's say I have an interface `IAutoTask` and few other classes implementing that interface, `RegularTextAnswerTask`, `SelectAnswerTask`, `JoinPairsTask` etc. Each of these classes defines an `EvaluateAnswer` method returning an int - but the parameter for the method differs.

```
public sealed class SelectAnswerTask : IAutoTask
{

    public int EvaluateAnswer(int[] answer);

}

public sealed class RegularTextAnswerTask : IAutoTask
{

    public int EvaluateAnswer(string answer);

}

public sealed class JoinPairsTask : IAutoTask
{

    public int EvaluateAnswer(int[,] answer);

}
```

Now, what should the definition of the interface look like? I came up with:

```
public interface IAutoTask<AnswerType>
{

    int EvaluateAnswer(AnswerType answer);

}
```

And modifying the implementors as follows:

```
public sealed class SelectAnswerTask : IAutoTask<int[]>
{

    public void EvaluateAnswer(int[] answer)
    {

    }

}
```

etc.

**Do you consider this approach to be a correct one?**

Comment: At least two things are  unclear - naming convention (Why you use suffix Type? is this a meta type of the answer? then why you evalueting it, how you can evaluate type of answer). And second thing - is unclear why you need abstract class there.

Comment: Well, it is my understanding that instead of AnswerType an actual type will be passed, hence the name. (It is the same as calling it T. Or am I wrong?) And, of course an abstract class is unnecessary the way it is now (empty), but it is a part of my design and will gain importance in close future.

Comment: i didn't even understand the problem description...

Comment: Sorry about that... I simplified my question.

Comment: What other methods would you have in your classes that implement `IAutoTask`?

Comment: Much of the functionality would allready be encapsulated in an abstract base class `AutoTask`. I cut it off for this post to make things simpler. This is very early design anyway in which these classes only represent a fact that different task types exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is acceptable, although the best design choice also depends on the way you expect the  consumers of your class (i.e. those that use `_____AnswerTask`) to use it.

[Naming conventions for Generic Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479858.aspx) suggest a slight modification to your interface definition:

```
public interface IAutoTask<TAnswer>
{

    int EvaluateAnswer(TAnswer answer);

}
```

Comment: I plan on adding an `Evaluator` class matching a given list of answers against a given list of tasks. `IAutoTask` implementors are capable of evaluating answers to themselves, therefore a `Test` consisting of a number of `IAutoTask`s is capable of evaluating itself. (The return value of `EvaluateAnswer` represents a number of points the student recieved answering that task.) Plus there are `ITaskRenderer`s constructing a GUI for the tasks. Thank you for suggesting an improvement.